# example showing Minkowski distance with $p<1$ is not a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

The Minkowski distance:
$$\left(\sum_i |x_i-x_i'|^p \right)^{1/p},\ \text{where}\ p\ge1$$

is only a metric for $p\ge1$. Can someone give me a quick example why the triangle inequality doesn't hold in other cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) has the following example:

Let $x := (0, 0)$, $y := (1, 1)$, $z := (0, 1)$.

Then:

- $d(x, y) = 2^{1/p}$, which when $p < 1$ is more than $2$.
- $d(x, z) = d(y, z) = 1$.

So $d(x, y) > d(x, z) + d(z, y)$.

Comment: Hey, cool, I get to upvote you twice.

Comment: @Dougal thanks! For some reason I only found the definition without the example.